# Display 4 level hierachy with php from data pulled from multiple mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I'm not a programmer of any sort, I play with php and mysql for my own entertainment, but at this point I have a problem that I cannot figure out how to fix.

I'm trying to display a tree of taxon in php, basically

genus
subgenus
species
subspecies

I manage to get to this point, I used truncated the sample from the database to keep it readable.

```
Genus: Agonum Bonelli, 1810
   Species: Agonum patinale Bates, 1882
   Species: Agonum scutiferum Bates, 1878
   Species: Agonum tropicum Motschulsky, 1864
   Species: Agonum bicolor (Dejean, 1828)
   Species: Agonum muelleri (Herbst, 1784)
   Species: Agonum piceolum (LeConte, 1879)
   Species: Agonum anchomenoides Randall, 1838
   Species: Agonum canadense Goulet, 1969
   Species: Agonum consimile (Gyllenhal, 1810)
   Species: Agonum aeruginosum Dejean, 1828
   Species: Agonum affine Kirby, 1837
   Species: Agonum albicrus Dejean, 1828
   Species: Agonum anthracinum Dejean, 1831
```

Or this if theres is subspecies

```
Genus: Apotomus Illiger, 1807
   Species: Apotomus angusticollis G. Müller, 1943
   Species: Apotomus annulaticornis Péringuey, 1896
        Subspecies: Apotomus annulaticornis annulaticornis Péringueyy, 1896
        Subspecies: Apotomus annulaticornis perrieri Jeannel, 1946
   Species: Apotomus atripennis Motschulsky, 1858
   Species: Apotomus australis Castelnau, 1867
   Species: Apotomus chaudoirii Wollaston, 1860
   Species: Apotomus clypeonitens G. Müller, 1943
        Subspecies: Apotomus clypeonitens adanensis Jedlicka, 1961
        Subspecies: Apotomus clypeonitens clypeonitens G. Müller, 1943
        Subspecies: Apotomus clypeonitens heinzi Wrase, 1992
   Species: Apotomus fairmairei Jeannel, 1946
   Species: Apotomus flavescens Apetz, 1854
```

The problem is, in the first sample there should be subgenus showing off like this

```
Genus: Agonum Bonelli, 1810
   Species: Agonum patinale Bates, 1882
   Species: Agonum scutiferum Bates, 1878
   Species: Agonum tropicum Motschulsky, 1864
     Subgenus: Agonum (Agonum) Bonelli, 1810
       Species: Agonum bicolor (Dejean, 1828)
       Species: Agonum muelleri (Herbst, 1784)
       Species: Agonum piceolum (LeConte, 1879)
     Subgenus: Agonum (Europhilus) Chaudoir, 1859
       Species: Agonum anchomenoides Randall, 1838
       Species: Agonum canadense Goulet, 1969
       Species: Agonum consimile (Gyllenhal, 1810)
     Subgenus: Agonum (Olisares) Motschulsky, 1865
       Species: Agonum aeruginosum Dejean, 1828
       Species: Agonum affine Kirby, 1837
       Species: Agonum albicrus Dejean, 1828
       Species: Agonum anthracinum Dejean, 1831
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the query to pull the data AND insert it where it should be in the tree.

In the Database I have a table for each one of the taxon Genus, Subgenus, Species, Subspecies as well as all the taxon above the genus one, Family, Order etc., they all have an ID i.e. genus_id, and a name genus_name all in the same format.

Here is the entire query (minus the database connection)

```
`$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Genus ORDER BY genus_name";`
`$res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);`

        while($g = mysqli_fetch_array($res2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          
             {      
                $genus_name = "".$g['genus_name']."";
                
                echo "<b>Genus: $genus_name<br></b>";
                
                    
                
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM Species WHERE genus_name =  '$genus_name'";
                     $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        
                       while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        
                         {
                          $kingdom_name = "".$d['kingdom_name']."";
                          $phylum_name = "".$d['phylum_name']."";
                          $subphylum_name = "".$d['subphylum_name']."";
                          $class_name = "".$d['class_name']."";
                          $subclass_name = "".$d['subclass_name']."";
                          $infraclass_name = "".$d['infraclass_name']."";
                          $superorder_name = "".$d['superorder_name']."";
                          $order_name = "".$d['order_name']."";
                          $suborder_name = "".$d['suborder_name']."";
                          $family_name   = "".$d['family_name']."";
                          $subfamily_name    = "".$d['subfamily_name']."";
                          $tribe_name = "".$d['tribe_name']."";
                          $genus_name = "".$d['genus_name']."";
                          $subgenus_name = "".$d['subgenus_name']."";
                          $species_name = "".$d['species_name']."";
                          $subspecies_name = "".$d['subspecies_name']."";
                     
                           
                   
                            if($species_name != '')
                             {
                              echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Species: $species_name<br>";
                             }
                            if($subspecies_name != '')
                             {
                              echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Subspecies: $subspecies_name<br>";
                             }
                         }
                   
             }
```

Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally with this type of stuff, I like to abstract away the problem into a data structure. The second step is turning the data structure into output, which is a separate concern. With this kind of data, while it's possible with an array, or even without abstracting away the problem, it's nice to have a DOM-like tree so you can always get the parent of a node. Ideally have a node class which can hold children which are also nodes. While you can use PHP's built in DOM manipulation, you can also build your own class for this because it's relatively straight forward:

```
<?php

class TreeNode
{
    protected $depth,$type,$text,$children,$parent;
    public function __construct(string $type = 'root', string $text = '')
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->depth = 0;
        $this->children = [];
    }
    public function setParent(TreeNode $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
    public function addChildNode(TreeNode $child)
    {
        $child->setParent($this);
        $child->setDepth($this->depth+1);
        $this->children[] = $child;
        return $child;
    }
    public function addChild(string $type, string $text)
    {
        return $this->addChildNode(new TreeNode($type,$text));
    }
    public function setDepth(int $depth)
    {
        $this->depth = $depth;
    }
    public function getDepth()
    {
         return $this->depth;
    }
    public function getText(){
        return $this->text;
    }
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
    public function nodeHtml()
    {
        if($this->type === 'root'){ return ''; }
        return str_repeat('&nbsp;',$this->depth*4).$this->type.': '.htmlentities($this->text);
    }
    public function treeHtml()
    {
        $out = $this->nodeHTML();
        if($this->type !== 'root'){ $out .= '<br>'; }
        foreach($this->children as $child)
        {
            $out .= $child->treeHtml();
        }
        return $out;
    }
}

$root = new TreeNode();
$pointer = $root->addChild('Genus', 'Agonum Bonelli, 1810');
$pointer->addChild('Species', 'Agonum patinale Bates, 1882');
$pointer->addChild('Species', 'Agonum scutiferum Bates, 1878');
$pointer = $pointer->addChild('Species', 'Agonum tropicum Motschulsky, 1864');
$pointer = $pointer->addChild('Subgenus','Agonum (Agonum) Bonelli, 1810');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum bicolor (Dejean, 1828)');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum muelleri (Herbst, 1784)');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum piceolum (LeConte, 1879)');
$pointer = $pointer->getParent();
$pointer = $pointer->addChild('Subgenus','Agonum (Europhilus) Chaudoir, 1859');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum anchomenoides Randall, 1838');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum canadense Goulet, 1969');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum consimile (Gyllenhal, 1810)');
$pointer = $pointer->getParent();
$pointer = $pointer->addChild('Subgenus','Agonum (Olisares) Motschulsky, 1865');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum aeruginosum Dejean, 1828');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum affine Kirby, 1837');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum albicrus Dejean, 1828');
$pointer->addChild('Species','Agonum anthracinum Dejean, 1831');
echo $root->treeHtml();
```

The output for this would be:

```
    Genus: Agonum Bonelli, 1810
        Species: Agonum patinale Bates, 1882
        Species: Agonum scutiferum Bates, 1878
        Species: Agonum tropicum Motschulsky, 1864
            Subgenus: Agonum (Agonum) Bonelli, 1810
                Species: Agonum bicolor (Dejean, 1828)
                Species: Agonum muelleri (Herbst, 1784)
                Species: Agonum piceolum (LeConte, 1879)
            Subgenus: Agonum (Europhilus) Chaudoir, 1859
                Species: Agonum anchomenoides Randall, 1838
                Species: Agonum canadense Goulet, 1969
                Species: Agonum consimile (Gyllenhal, 1810)
            Subgenus: Agonum (Olisares) Motschulsky, 1865
                Species: Agonum aeruginosum Dejean, 1828
                Species: Agonum affine Kirby, 1837
                Species: Agonum albicrus Dejean, 1828
                Species: Agonum anthracinum Dejean, 1831
```

It should be easy enough to modify to suit your needs.
Basically the looping should look something like this:
set the $pointer to the root node before any looping. Do your outer loop:

```
$pointer = $root->addChild('Genus', 'Agonum Bonelli, 1810');
```

if there's any inner loops to do, the pointer would already be set to the child that was just inserted. Once you finish the inner loops, as the last line in the outer loop, you'd do:

```
$pointer = $pointer->getParent();
```

This logic can be repeated for any nesting, all you'd need is reference the pointer's parent when you need to insert a node higher in the tree. You can also store references to a specific node and the reference will be kept if you need to insert stuff out of order.

I trust you'll be able to move this over to your looping.